# How do so many high end oscilloscopes support Gsps when most microcontrollers have ADC rates at Msps?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, oscilloscope

How do so many high end oscilloscopes support scanning rates at Gsps?
Most micro controllers have ADCs reading only at few Msps.

Comment: Dedicated external ADC ICs are a thing and came into existence before microcontrollers could integrate ADCs into themselves.

Comment: They also use multiple ADCs with time-division.

Comment: It's mainly economical: In an DSO, the ADC is a core part and its speed defines the league the DSO is in. So it's okay if it's an expensive part on the bill of material. And a high-speed ADC is expensive. In a microcontroller, a high speed ADC is rarely used. So a low price for this component is is far more important than it's speed.

Comment: All that, and if you have a Gsps ADC on a typical microcontroller, the data has nowhere to go -- you usually find Gsps ADC's connected to FPGAs.

Comment: The prefixes m and M are very different.

Comment: Not with microcontrollers.

Comment: A big part of it is that those Gsps ADCs themselves are quite big, expensive and power hungry chips. I mean, just check out the 10Gsps [AD9213](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad9213.html#product-overview), 4.5W at full tilt and US3k *in quantity*... and that's ***just*** for the ADC, data processing costs extra (and with x16 16Gbit data lanes, that'd saturate a PCIe gen4 x16 slot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use purpose build ADCs with the capability of sampling in the regions of Gsps. If they need more, there is a clever scheme of using multiple ADCs at the same time with a very well defined time delay between them, so that two ADCs work as one ADC with double the sampling rate.

For this to work properly, the analog bandwidth of the ADC must be higher than the sample rate, which might seem strange at first (aliasing) but the signal should not be distorted, and the digital bandwidth of the complete system will define the Nyquist frequency. The scheme can of course be enhanced to use more than two ADCs for a single channel to increase the rate even further.

On many multichannel oscilloscopes you will notice that using certain channels together halves the sampling rate. For example using Channel 1 and 2 on my Keysight oscilloscope will half the sampling rate while using Channel 1 and 3 will not. The reason being that the ADC for Channel 1 and 2 can work together as one and Channel 3 and 4 can work together as one.

You typical microcontroller will also be much too slow to handle all the data coming from those ADCs in. So you probably find a FPGA or ASIC as the next step in the signal chain which does the signal processing.

The ADCs will cost you hundreds of dollars alone, without anything supporting it. The only microcontrollers in that price region I've seen where military, space or extreme environment stuff.

Comment: correct. + ASIC's in the Frontend of the ADC's + multiple FPGA'S for Data Preprocessing, Triggering, Filtering,... + normal PC's for display and control..., as stated, the used FPGA's alone are some 50-100$/€ per pice. The ADC's and ASIC's are special and for sure not high volume stuff: very expensive. Even my 400€ scope has a FPGA with some ARM Cores for Linux (display + frontpanel). They use of the shelf 1GSps ADC's which at 8Bit is 8GBit/s! thats already pretty fast for these "cheep" devices

Comment: Thanks. There would be a ADC reading lag and even the instruction execution lag by the cpu, all that would have to be read and saved before the next sample comes. So the controller could even continue sampling for few more seconds and gather even more resolution?

Comment: @thevikas you often have the possibility to switch to a "high resolution" mode, which effectively makes the scope sample at a higher rate and combine multiple samples into one display sample with an average value. This increases resolution and decreases noise, but can trick you as the averaging alters the shape of the signal (especially fast ones). Also note that modern oscilloscopes take up to 100k waveforms per second, so the frontend is always very busy and some tricky stuff is happening to decide what and how to display it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good reason we don't see fpga and MCU with higher speed adc.

100MSPS could be easily integrated into the higher end devices.

Apparently there is a 80 MSPS NXP cortex device.